# Изменение цвета текста в EditText после определенной длины

Tags: android

В общем нужно менять цвет текста после определенной длины, сейчас делаю так

```
protected TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    private long lastPostTypingTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() >= TYPING_DURATION) {
            s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), TYPING_DURATION, s.length(),  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }
};
```

При неразрывной печати после определенного колич. символов текст нормально меняет цвет на красный, при удалении с конца строки, тоже все проходит нормально. Проблема, когда удаляется допустим часть символов из середины текста, тогда общая длина текста становится < TYPING_DURATION, но текст выделенный красным остается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы при каждом изменении навешиваете новый span на текст, хотя это достаточно делать 1 раз, если его ещё нет. Ну и в else проверять и снимать span, если он есть.

Comment: спасибо, приму к сведению

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    for (ForegroundColorSpan span : s.getSpans(0, s.length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class)) {
        s.removeSpan(span);
    }
    if (s.length() >= TYPING_DURATION) {
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), TYPING_DURATION, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

на `beforeTextChanged` запоминайте сколько было символов а на `afterTextChanged` проверяйте.